# Всё таки/Всё-таки (особый случай, совы!)

Tags: орфография

Мне почему-то кажется, что именно в данном случае (когда *всё* - это подлежащие или дополнение) дефис не нужен, так как иначе даже значение может-таки стать другим. Совы, опровергните Вы меня, пожалуйста, или наоборот!

1. Всё таки было хорошо. (*Всё* - подлежащие.)
2. Я ненавижу всё таки о ней-то. (*Всё* - дополнение таки.)

Comment: Да, может. В первом случае всё - местоимение, во втором - наречие. Но олед не согласится.

Comment: Я тоже не соглашусь. Нельзя так писать! Нельзя!! ))

Comment: @Буратино Часть речи определяется по вопросу. У наречия вопрос "как?". Во втором примере он не подходит. И там и там четвёртый пункт: https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/весь Учитесь говорить с аргументами. Здесь так положено. (Аргументом может быть ссылка.)

Comment: @Sharon Он этого не понимает. Он думает, что грамотность заключается только в орфографии и пунктуации.

Comment: Я ненавижу как? - всё, то есть полностью, а не это целое. Всё - это и полностью, и целое. Аргумент - не обязательно ссылка. И я рад, что ты вышел из образа.

Answer (score 2):

**Дополню-таки немного для ясности.**

(1) ***Все таки / было хорошо.*** Правка орфографии: ***Все-таки / было хорошо.***

Ничего не изменилось в смысле предложения, то же значение частицы "всё-таки", только **нет орфографической ошибки**.

**Словарь:** II. частица. Подчёркивает скрытое противопоставление. Как в. приятно приезжать сюда. Может, в. согласишься?  <Всё ж таки, союз и частица.

Всё – это **подлежащее**? А кто об этом догадается? А вот ошибку все заметят.

(2) ***Я ненавижу всё / таки о ней-то.***

Смысл сказанного можно только **угадать**, как и значение частицы ТО (она-то здесь зачем). Выбрать вариант прочтения тоже затруднительно. **Ребус**, а не предложение,  его нужно полностью перестраивать.

Всё – это **дополнение?** Опять та же картина: **кто об этом догадается?** Чтобы оно стало дополнением, нужно переставить частицу в другое место. А в заданном предложении отметят **орфографическую, стилистическую и грамматическую ошибку.** Еще хуже, чем в первом.

Чтобы **составлять** предложения, надо понимать структуру предложения, а это **не так просто, как кажется.**

**Цитата:**  *Я хочу знать правила и уметь даже так написать, то есть, может быть, не очень верно логически, но зато очень-таки **орфографически** правильно-таки!*

Что же вы раньше-то **молчали!** Там где нет логики и смысла, не может быть никакой правильности. Правильность, она, как и свежесть, **только одна** –  это когда все правильно.

Answer (score 0):

У меня появилась очередная странная идея, почему собственно всё это наречие или местоимение.

Местоимение когда в-сё или в-сих(всех), когда это замета указательного местоимения.

В сё таки было хорошо. Предлагаю писать раздельно.

А вот : я ненавижу всё таки о ней-то. - на распадается, потому что я ненавижу не что-то в сё, а что-то в ней, можно заменить наречием полностью это о ней. В не принадлежит сё: я ненавижу во ней-то сё - это/каждое самое.

Кстати, а кто она, кого вы так ненавидите?

Comment: Странные идеи бывают от странных стихов. Боже вас сохрани, не читайте их больше. Вы ведь не поэт, нет?  Такие стихи нужны только для вдохновения)) А у Шанского вот что написано https://lexicography.online/etymology/shansky/в/весь

Comment: @Sharon не знаю как у Шанского и у индоевропейцев, в русском они разваливаются на части - в есть. Что-то есть и в нем. Есть - это не чувство, а то что можно есть, еда, то что причиняет чувства. Как бы объяснить. Есть мир внешний - мир вещей, то, что чувства вызывает, а есть внутреннее духовное, то что до чувства, вне чувства. И они очень четко маркируются русским языком. То есть я задаюсь вопросом, не относительно формы, меня не очень волнует как это писать, но мне важно понять почему пишут так, говорят так, а не иначе.

Comment: И я нахожу массу подтверждения моей догадке, что в русском слова делятся на те, которые относятся только к внешнему миру, а есть те, которые относятся ко внутреннему. Например, на такие слова указывает, кроме того что я написал, добавление -о -е. Есть разница к или ко, также как оно или оное. Есть разница употребляется звонкий или глухой согласный в корне - лож или лаг. Это используется для следующего: вот у вас есть коробка. Если вы хотите описать то, что находится снаружи - вы скажете о, если внутри то в, а как указать границу между в и о? получается во. Не в мне, а во мне.

Comment: Или вот еще: вы видите бревно - это лог, оно лежит(находится в состоянии лежания). Но оно легло - это выполнило не пассивное, а активное действие, само легло, а не находилось под воздействием лежания. То есть легло - это субъектное действие, а лежало - это объект или, кто-то его положил. В русском это не совсем так работает что ли. Легло - это внешнее действие, видимое, а лежать - это предполагаемое, то что является причиной, а не действием, состояние, а не действие. Поэтому мне, конечно, интересно читать о происхождениях корней, но мне нравится и сравнивать.

Comment: Ну и как вы писали, что скоро начнете меня понимать, у меня есть чувство, что я сам себя наконец пойму)

Answer (score 0):

**Редактирование:**

(1) ***ВсЁ было / хорошО-таки.***  (2) ***Я таки ненавИжу / всЁ о ней.***

**Пояснение**

1. Письменная форма предложения должна выражать **смысл**, но для этого нужно подобрать **нужную структуру** с корректной расстановкой ударений в устной речи.
2. Это **простое** предложение, и оно должно соответствовать следующим **требованиям**:

(1) Высказывание состоит из двух частей: **тема** (о чем говорится) в первой части и  рема  (что говорится) во второй части.

(2) Предложение состоит **из двух фраз** (повышение и понижение тона), разделенных паузой.

(3) ***ТАКИ*** – это усилительно-выделительная частица, она должна относиться к **нужному** слову. Но наши возможности в этом плане **ограниченны**, поэтому строим такое предложение, где смысл максимально **приближен** к заданному. И вот **предлагаемая** структура **НЕ ОТВЕЧАЕТ** указанным требованиям.

3. Эти требования присутствуют постоянно в нашей речи, но носители языка правильно строят предложения **интуитивно.**  Но для нестандартных фраз пришлось применить эти правила.

Comment: Это просто попытка избежать незнания, как объяснить, как правильно писать! Я не хочу пытаться всё время обходные пути находить, когда я не знаю, как что-то правильно написать! Я хочу знать правила и уметь даже так написать, то есть, может быть, не очень верно логически, но зато очень-таки орфографически правильно-таки!

Comment: @Pumpkin777 правильное - это результат какого-то действия, итог оценки какого-то действия. Действия или сказанное это суть бред, пока он не оценен. То есть блуждание. А причина - бреда-блуждания(но еще не заблуждения или чего-то верного) не есть правило, а как раз есть незнание, вопрос по отношении к кажущемуся знанию, реально оно или нет, есть оно или нет. Поэтому формализм, особенно касательно русского языка - это тупиковый путь, потому что правил в русском будет столько, сколько смыслов туда вложено.

Comment: С другой стороны, если ты хочешь найти причину почему пишется так, то тебе стоит обратить внимание не на графию, а на орфо. Что такое орфо, орфос? А точнее даже на ор в орфос.